# Store multiple different dynamcially added items into array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create an array when im using TMDB(The movie database) API, I am using [this](http://code.octal.es/php/tmdb-api/class-Movie.html) wrapper for PHP.

I am trying to do this

```
require_once('../classes/tmdb-api.php');

// if you have no $conf it uses the default config
$tmdb = new TMDB(); 

//Insert your API Key of TMDB
//Necessary if you use default conf
$tmdb->setAPIKey('myKEy');

//Title to search for
$title = $_POST['searchTerm'];
$movies = $tmdb->searchMovie($title);
// returns an array of Movie Object

$movieArray = array();
$movieSearchArray = array();

foreach($movies as $movie) {
    $movieTitle = $movie->getTitle();
    $movieSearchArray[$movieTitle] = ['ID'][$movie->getID()];
    $movieSearchArray[$movieTitle] = ['Trailer'][$movie->getTrailer()];
}

$movieArray[] = $movieSearchArray;

print_r($movieArray);
```

So for example when a user searches 'Rocky' It will bring back multiple different movie titles but for each of the movie titles I want to create an array like this for example, I am trying to do this in the foreach loop but what am i doing wrong?

```
[Rocky] => (
   "id" = "2",
   "rating" = "4"
)
```

Keep in mind that there could be 10s of different movies. This is what i get returned when I search 'Rocky' right now.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Rocky] => 
            [Rocky II] => 
            [Rocky IV] => 
            [Rocky V] => 
            [Rocky Balboa] => 
            [Rocky III] => 
            [Rocky VI] => 
            [Creed] => 
            [The Real Rocky] => 
            [Rocky Marciano] => 
            [Where is Rocky II?] => 
            [Rocky Handsome] => 
            [Rocky Road] => 
            [Rocky Mountain] => 
            [Rocky Pink] => 
            [Rocky and Bullwinkle] => 
            [The Rocky Horror Picture Show] => 
            [Rocky Mountain Grandeur] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: I guess you shouldn't put assignment for your school test or homework here as it is.

Comment: sorry, please see my solution bellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can do that, with only exception of assigning item to an array, indices in [] must be before equal (=) sign, or you have to assign whole array with keys and values.

so either

```
foreach($movies as $movie) {
    $movieTitle = $movie->getTitle();
    $movieSearchArray[$movieTitle]['ID'] = $movie->getID();
    $movieSearchArray[$movieTitle]['Trailer'] = $movie->getTrailer(); 
}
```

or

```
foreach($movies as $movie) {
    $movieSearchArray[$movie->getTitle()] = array(
        'ID' => $movie->getID(),
        'Trailer' => $movie->getTrailer()
    );
}
```

and so on for other data in the $movie object

Comment: You beat me to the punch by about two seconds.  +1

Comment: It would be nice to see how others are typing their solution side by side with yours :)

Comment: Your part one was identical.